# do not want blank image in repeater if not in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

A database query inserts into a repeater. One of the fields is an image. Only some of the rows of data have an image, so If they do have an image, it works fine, but if there is no image in the database, it shows a blank spot where the image should be. I want it to not have that blank image render if there is no image in database. How do I do this? Some of the rows have the Image and some do not. I want to display all the rows, but where ther is no image, I do not want a blank image to appear

```
asp:Repeater id="cdcatalog" runat="server" onitemcreated="cdcatalog_ItemCreated" onitemcommand="cdcatalog_ItemCommand">

            <ItemTemplate>
  <    img src='<%# "/contents/thumbs/" + Eval("ThumbName")%>' width="375px"   height="200px"        
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>

Page Load:
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * From Video", con)
        Dim ds = New DataSet()
        Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds)

        cdcatalog.DataSource = ds
        cdcatalog.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to check what you get from database before you put it into repeater control. If image doesn’t exist then you can add some default image instead of it like empty.png that will be 1px X 1px.

One solution is to update your SQL query that gets the data and use ISNULL to provide default empty image.

Another solution is to do this in ASP.NET like this (basically same as rs showed)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href='<% #GetImageURL(Eval("ThumbName")) %>'></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Then just create protected GetImageURL in the same web form that does all the math and shows some default image if provided doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

Change your aspx image tag to call function from codebehind, Try this

```
 <img src='<%# "/contents/thumbs/" + Eval("ThumbName")%>' 
  width="375px"   height="200px" visible='<%# ShowImage(Eval("ThumbName"))%>'
```

Codebehind

```
Protected Function ShowImage(name As Object) As [boolean]
If name IsNot Nothing Then
    Return name.ToString().Trim().Length > 0
End If
Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Question: This didn't work. The ThumbName column either has an integer in it or it is NULL or it is 0. In all cases, it shows the blank image, or an image if there is one. How do I get the value of Thumbname to the function? I see showimage(name as object). how is it getting name from the repeater?

Comment: what are valid values for thumbname? check this property `visible='<%# ShowImage(Eval("ThumbName"))%>'` this is passing name to codebehind